# How to Cancel Intent Called From startActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-intent, startactivityforresult

When you call/start a activity using `startActivityForResult` function (In my case it is for Facebook login with `LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS);` is there any way to cancel the intent so parent activity `onActivityResult` will not be called. I want to add a timeout mechanism to my parent activity to prevent long waiting times for the child activity. (When Facebook is blocked/slowed down it takes minutes until `onActivityResult` is called , so i want to inform the user about the situation on possible timeout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't cancel it. However, you could keep track of the fact that you aren't waiting for the `onActivityResult()` callback any more so that when the method does get called, you remember that you don't care and just ignore it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , actually I have already followed/implemented the same approach you have suggested. But as i have also investigated there is no way to cancel an intent .

Answer (score 0):

You could `setResult(TIMEOUT)` before finishing your activity and check the result in your `onActivityResult`.

Besides, best practice would be to set your timeout mechanism inside your child activity (you can pass some information in your intent).

Comment: Thank you for answer , but child activity is not my activity it is 3rd part activity (Actually it is FacebookActivity which handles facebook login and send back result to parent activity ) . So i can't call `setResult(TIMEOUT)` from child activity. I need to tell Android OS to "cancel my request from child activity" .

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit old, but I was just facing the same issue where the activity started by *startActivityForResult(Intent, REQUEST_CODE)* is from a 3rd party which means that there is no way I can manually finish it or set a result before finishing it.

But luckily android provides an activity method for that, just call it from the parent activity that started the 3rd party one.

```
Activity.finishActivity(REQUEST_CODE)
```

The ***REQUEST_CODE*** is the code you send earlier to *emphasized text*